# xamarin Auth for facebook authentication scenarios

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, xamarin

I am developing an application using xamarin.Here I am using xamarin auth component for facebook authentication.I am able to login and get users info and able to save them in local DB.Xamarin auth component has provided option for storing account object so that when user relaunch app ,we can use that account object to login.

Here comes my question: If user changes password on facebook account from site then what should be done when app is relaunching,as stored account is local we can't use that info to login again.

Thanks.
Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you are supposed to use the access_token for subsequent queries towards Facebook after the first successful authentication. With OAuth, you won't store password in your app. I would expect that when a user changes the password within Facebook, the old access_token might expire. In this case, you'll have to make the user manually re-login. This is the case anyhow when your access_token expires for any reason; keep in mind that all access_tokens expire after some time.

You can easily verify if the access_token is still valid by sending some basic request in the background. If you get an autherror response, just prompt the user to login again when it makes sense in the flow of your app.